# Stop postback on ajax error

Tags: return, postback

I have an asp button with both onclick and onclientclick events. onclientclick, it calls a js function to save. if the save has any error, i want to stop the onclick event. i tried e.preventdefault(), e.stopPropogation(), return false. nothing seems to work. heres my code :
button :

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewAddr" runat="server" onclick="btnAddNewAddr_Click" OnClientClick="SaveLocAddress();" class="btn btn-primary" 
            Text="Save Address" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
```

js savemethod:

```
function SaveLocAddress(e) {
    if (validaddr) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "post",
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "JSON",
                url: "/Pages/Location/Search.aspx/SaveLocationAddress",
                data: "{ addrDTO: " + JSON.stringify(`addrToSave`) + "}",
                success: function (xhr, ts, error) {
                    AlertAddrSuccess(id);
                },
                error: function () {
                    console.log('error');
                    AlertAddrError();
                    e.stopPropogation();

                },
                complete: function () {
                    if ($('#alertAddressError').text() != "")
                        return false;
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX runs *asynchronously*.  So two things are happening here:

1. The event is propagating before your callback handlers are even being invoked (before there's a response from the AJAX call).
2. The callback handlers aren't attached to the context of the `SaveLocAddress` when they're invoked, so the `return` statements don't go anywhere.

This is probably going to require a little bit of re-design.  Maybe two buttons?  One would be the `asp:Button` but is styled to be invisible.  The other is a normal `button` which has the text/styling you want the button to have.  The order of events would be:

1. User clicks the HTML button
2. A JavaScript button handler invokes the AJAX call
3. Depending on the AJAX response, it triggers the `click` event on the hidden button.

It's kind of a round-about way of doing things, but that's WebForms for you.  It might be something like this:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnAddNewAddr" runat="server" onclick="btnAddNewAddr_Click" class="btn btn-primary invisible" UseSubmitBehavior="false" />
<input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save Address" onclick="SaveLocAddress();" />
```

Then in your JavaScript code where you want to invoke the post-back functionality you might do something like:

```
$('#<%= btnAddNewAddr.ClientID %>').trigger('click');
```

That would trigger the `click` event on the `asp:button` as though the user had clicked it.

Comment: i added async: false to make the ajax call synchronous. i dont understand return false is not going anywhere. Can you please explain "The callback handlers aren't attached to the context of the SaveLocAddress when they're invoked." Thanks!!

Comment: @Sri: Ah, I'd missed the `async:false`, though I don't recommend its use.  It's better to use asynchronous designs effectively than to just give up and make them synchronous.  For your question, though, the `return` statements are being executed inside an anonymous function, *not* in `SaveLocAddress`.  You're returning from `complete: function () { ... }`, which doesn't "return" anywhere.  If the whole thing is synchronous, then at the start of `SaveLocAddress` you can set a value, update the value in the callback functions, then at the end of `SaveLocAddress` check the value and return.

Comment: I tried doing the counter. It is returning false. But, in the browser, it is rendering the button as  <input type="button" name="ctl00$MainContent$CurrentResultDetails$LocContact$btnAddNewAddr" value="Save Address" onclick="SaveLocAddress();__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$MainContent$CurrentResultDetails$LocContact$btnAddNewAddr&#39;,&#39;&#39;)" id="MainContent_CurrentResultDetails_LocContact_btnAddNewAddr" />. And, if you notice, "SaveLocAddress(); _doPostback(blahblah'). it is not stopping with return false. I will try invisble button workaround and will let you know. Thanks alot

Comment: @Sri: That looks like a pretty standard WebForms rendering.  Is it not working in some way?

Comment: i am not sure why its not stopping onerror. i tried preventDefualt too.

Comment: @Sri: At this point I would guess that the call to `__doPostBack` is happening regardless of the result of `SaveLocAddress()` in that `onclick` attribute on the `input`.  This may still call for two buttons to get around that.

Comment: how about, making the button a regular html button and doing an explicit postback on success? can i do that?

Comment: @Sri: You can.  I've always tried to avoid manually calling `__doPostBack` in JavaScript code, but there's no reason why it can't be done.

Comment: Thanks for all the help. I changed it to __doPostback and its working as desired. Can I know why its not recommended? In my case, I have a grid of addresses, when new one is added or modified(done via bootstrap modal and ajax post), grid is not refreshing. So, I had to call a server method to refresh the grid.